# microsoft dynamics crm 2015 Error in javascript string concatenation

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to concatenate two strings to make it a useful link. The code goes here:

```
ODataHost = "https://xyz.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/";
accountId= "{90639159-6E01-E511-80ED-C4346BADA644}";
ODataquery = "AccountSet(guid'" + accountId + "')";
ODataURL= ODataHost + ODataquery;
```

ODataURL which is not forming a meaningful link and is distorted. The link that is formed is:
`https://xyz.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'{90639159-6E01-E511-80ED-C4346BADA644}')`  ,but the last characters of the resulting string i.e }') are not a part of resultant string which makes it a distorted link. 
I have also tried: ODataHost = ODataHost.concat(ODataQuery) but this didn't worked.
Please come with a suitable solution .

Comment: Did you try accountId = accountId.slice(1,-1); ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `{}`, going from this:

```
https://xyz.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'{90639159-6E01-E511-80ED-C4346BADA644}')
```

to this

```
https://xyz.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'90639159-6E01-E511-80ED-C4346BADA644')
```